# Android emulator using genymotion hangs after coming back from laptop sleep

Tags: genymotion

I am using genymotion emulator for android. Whenever i put my laptop in sleep and come back, the emulator hangs. I can see the screen, but mouse click does not work.

How to use the emulator even after coming back from sleep.